# MYSQL Trigger using XML Extractvalue

Tags: mysql, triggers

I get an error trying to create a trigger in MySQL using the ExtractValue function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER biblioitems_after_marcxml_update 
    AFTER UPDATE ON biblioitems
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
            INSERT IGNORE INTO X_BIBLIONUMBER_BIBID VALUES (NEW.biblionumber, EXTRACTVALUE(NEW.marcxml,  '//controlfield[@tag="001"]' ));
    END
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using DELIMITER?

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER biblioitems_after_marcxml_update AFTER UPDATE ON biblioitems
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO X_BIBLIONUMBER_BIBID
    VALUES
    (NEW.biblionumber, EXTRACTVALUE(NEW.marcxml, '//controlfield[@tag="001"]'));
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That was it.. I thought I did try this. many thanks! @wchiquito